# Как нарисовать строку при помощи вложенного цикла javascript

Tags: javascript

С помощью вложенных циклов нарисуйте строку:

```
1<br>
*_*_*_<br>
2<br>
*_*_*_<br>
3<br>
*_*_*_<br>
```

```
let out = document.querySelector('.out-');
    
          function t2() {
            out.innerHTML = '';
              for (let i = 1; i < 3 + 1; i++){
                for (let k = 1; k < 3+ 1; k++){
                  out.innerHTML += '*' + '_';
            }
            out.innerHTML += i + '<br>';
        }
    }
    document.querySelector('.b-2').onclick = t2;
```

С моим кодом почему-то не получается, как надо, подскажите, как сделать? Буду благодарен)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function t2() {
    let str = '';
    for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        str += i+'<br/>\n';
        for (let j = 1; j < 4; j++){
           str += '*';  
           for (let k = 1; k < 2; k++){
               str += '_';  
           }
        }
        str += '<br/>\n';  
    }
    return str;
}
console.log( t2() );
```

Результат

```
1<br/>
*_*_*_<br/>
2<br/>
*_*_*_<br/>
3<br/>
*_*_*_<br/>
```